# ArrayList , JFrame, JLabel

Tags: java

I am trying to create and simple program that has the user input 4 fields using the JFrame and textfields. Save those into a class. Put that class into an ArrayList (So they have the option to delete / or add more "classes" to it later). Then display all the contents of the ArrayList on one Frame.

I got the four fields to work I believe , but the part where the ArrayList contents are supposed to be displayed is not working ( I get a blank frame ).

this is my add into the arrayList ..

```
public void newEntryFrame()
{
    JFrame entryFrame = new JFrame("Passafe");
    entryFrame.setVisible(true);
    entryFrame.setSize(500, 500);
    entryFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    entryFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    entryFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    header.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 16));
    entryFrame.add(header);
    entryFrame.add(nameLabel);
    entryFrame.add(nametf);
    entryFrame.add(usernameLabel);
    entryFrame.add(usernametf);
    entryFrame.add(passwordLabel);
    entryFrame.add(passwordtf);
    entryFrame.add(descriptionLabel);
    entryFrame.add(descriptiontf);
    entryFrame.add(enterButton);

    enterButton.addActionListener(this);


}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
    Object source = event.getSource();

    if(source == enterButton)
    {
        name = nametf.getText();
        description = descriptiontf.getText();
        username = usernametf.getText();
        password = passwordtf.getText();
        totalEntries++;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SAVED");

    }
    else if(source == okButton)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ok Button Works");
    }



}
```

this is what I have to display the arrayList.

```
public void viewEntryFrame()
{
    JFrame viewFrame = new JFrame("Passafe");
    viewFrame.setSize(500, 500);
    viewFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    viewFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    viewFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    viewFrame.add(listHeader);

    newEntry tempView = new newEntry();

    for(int i = 0; i < totalEntries; ++i)
    {
        tempView = entries.get(i);
        viewFrame.add(tempView.display);
    }

    viewFrame.add(okButton);
    okButton.addActionListener(this);
    viewFrame.setVisible(true);

}
```

I might be doing this completely wrong if so could you point me in the right direction.

Comment: Where do you add to the `ArrayList`? Where do you even *create* the `ArrayList`?

Comment: What is `newEntry` class?

Comment: In your `actionPerformed` method, you never add anything to the `entries` `ArrayList`.  Also, you don't "really" need `totalEntries`, as `ArrayList` has a `size` method, meanining, instead of `for(int i = 0; i < totalEntries; ++i)`, you could actually do `for(newEntry tempView : entries)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you ever called `setContentPane()` A JFrame has only one component in the main part of it.  You have to create a JPanel to which you can add all of the components you want, then add that to your JFrame.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(/**whatever you want in your JFrame**/);
//...
panel.add(/**whatever you want in your JFrame**/);
frame.setContentPane(panel);
```

Answer (score 0):

You never seem to be adding anything to your `entries` list...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
    Object source = event.getSource();

    if(source == enterButton)
    {
        name = nametf.getText();
        description = descriptiontf.getText();
        username = usernametf.getText();
        password = passwordtf.getText();
        totalEntries++;
        // Nope, nothing here...
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SAVED");

    }
    //...
}
```

Also, this is very dangrouos...

```
newEntry tempView = new newEntry();

for(int i = 0; i < totalEntries; ++i)
{
    tempView = entries.get(i);
    viewFrame.add(tempView.display);
}
```

Rather the relying on the actual side of the `ArrayList`, you relying on some other variable, which may or may not equal the actual size, instead you should be using `ArrayList#size`, for example

```
for(int i = 0; i < entries.size(); ++i)
{
    newEntry tempView = entries.get(i);
    viewFrame.add(tempView.display);
}
```

Or if you're using Java 5+...

```
for(newEntry tempView : enties)
{
    viewFrame.add(tempView.display);
}
```